# Add gradient below SKShapeNode

Tags: sprite-kit, swift4, skspritenode

I am working on a graph like this in `watchKit`.

[image]

I have successfully draw line graph like above image according to custom data but I am unable to draw gradient below line graph like above image.

here what I have done:

```
 var points = [CGPoint(x: 0, y: 20),
                      CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10),
                      CGPoint(x: 25, y: 25),
                      CGPoint(x: 45, y: 5),
                      CGPoint(x: 60, y: 10),
                      CGPoint(x: 75, y: 0),
                      CGPoint(x: 90, y: 25),
                      CGPoint(x: 110, y: 0),
                      CGPoint(x: 125, y: 25)]
        let shape = SKShapeNode(splinePoints: &points,
                                          count: points.count)
        shape.strokeColor = UIColor.white
        shape.lineWidth = 2

        let gradientShader = SKShader(source: "void main() {" +
            "float normalisedPosition = v_path_distance / u_path_length;" +
            "gl_FragColor = vec4(normalisedPosition, normalisedPosition, 0.0, 1.0);" +
            "}")
       // shape.strokeShader = gradientShader

        addChild(shape)
```

This will code will draw a graph like this. (like graph is perfect but issue is in gradient also I have tried `SKShader`).

[image]

Comment: Let me know if you get any solution

Comment: Well a good way to cheat is to repeatedly add the same graph by doing a loop where you decrease the y value on each iteration and change the color to suit your gradients

Comment: @Knight0fDragon but i guess that will consume much memory on watch.

Comment: Not if you convert to a sprite node and share the texture through all nodes

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Can you please show me any example of that so i can get idea.

Answer (score 0):

You should review an excellent tutorial that seems to be similar to this problem on [Ray Wenderlich's site](https://www.raywenderlich.com/162313/core-graphics-tutorial-part-2-gradients-contexts)

The specific instructions from the linked location are in section titled "A Gradient Graph"

You'll need to make your path a clipping path, then fill the area under the path with a linear gradient.